# How to start download ubuntu 14.04

Tags: zsync

I decided to switch to the new LTS Ubuntu 14.04. Due to the low network speed downloading it will take some days. So it take some time to get the new Ubuntu after release. To avoid the delay I decide to download right now.
The plan is start download currently available  iso image (alpha, beta, daily build or something else I don't know) from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases. After downloading iso file, download the .zsync file, which wall be available after the final release.  Using that .iso file and .zsync make the final release as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage).
The problem is I don't know which iso file should be selected to download. There are many files (alpha, beta, daily build or something else I don't know). AFAIK .zsync files made from different base files will be different.

Which .iso file and .zsync files should I download to make the final release of Ubuntu 14.04

edit : from the comment from @the_Seppi, I understand  I can use the same zsync file for  alpha, beta, daily builds. Am I right ?

Comment: None of them are the final version until time of release.

Comment: I recommend download daily build, install it then upgrade inside installed system. If you want ISO image updated too, then use zsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to get the Beta-ISO for your architecture (amd64,i386,...) and the zsync file for the release of the same architecture.

So you can update i.e. a amd64 Trusty Beta to an amd64 Trusty FinalRelease. If you download the ISO for the wrong arch, you'll have to update large parts of the ISO, because nearly every binary file will change...

Comment: After downloading beta and zsync files, can I make the final iso from an offline machine. What contains in the zsync file, Diff data or information.

Comment: I don't know but if I had to guess I'd say it contains checksums which are compared with the existent ISO and changes are downloaded. So you certainly need to be online.

Comment: So I can use the same zsync file for  alpha, beta, daily builds. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. The zsync file is specific for the target file.